# Another java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the file specified) thread

Tags: java, file, text, path

I've created a basic notepad text file (e.g., text-file.txt) and have tried placing this file in multiple file paths for my code to retrieve, but I can't seem to get this to work. Basically, I'm wanting to take the content of text-file.txt and create a second file where everything is in all caps.

Here is my code:

```
package abc123;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class abc123
{
        public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
        {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

            System.out.print("Please provide the name of your input file: ");
            String inFileName = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please indicate what you'd like to name your output file: ");
            String outFileName = in.nextLine();

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(inFileName);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFileName); 
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(reader); 

            while(fileReader.hasNext())
            {
                    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
                    line = line.toUpperCase();
                    writer.println(line);
            }

            fileReader.close();
            writer.close();

            System.out.println("The process is now complete. Please check your output file. Thank you.");
        }
}
```

I'm a Java newbie, so a simple solution (and comments, as always) that I can grasp at this point would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this with `ios`, but I'll assume you're using Windows. Have you tried just putting your textfile at let's say `C:\text-file.txt` and entering `C:\text-file.txt` when you're running the application? You might  also want to use `fileReader.hasNextLine()` instead of `fileReader.hasNext()`.

Comment: Ha, yeah not sure how the "ios" got there. So, I made the fileReader.hasNextLine() modification and also placed my file in C:\ and following your suggestion. Now I am getting the following error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\new-text-file.txt (Access is denied)". Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I just created a folder in C;\, put my file in there, specified that new path, and NOW the program works. Yay! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if the file isn't in the same folder as your java class, you have to give java full-path to find the file. be sure you also type the extension of the file, like ".txt".

Comment: Thanks! I was including the file extension but wasn't typing out the full path correctly before, and now it works like a charm.